# Edit file on several lines with different strings

Tags: bash

I'm working on a script that will look in a file on all lines to find if a string A is followed by a string B on the following line. If that is not true it will add string C.

I have managed to do this but I want to do it in several places in the file. Like this

```
#!/bin/bash

match="match1"
match_following_line="following1"
insert='line_insert1'

file='words'
testfile='testfile'

#find linenumber for the first match
linenumber=$(awk -v myvar="$match" '$0~myvar {print NR}' $file)

#calculate linenumber for the comming line
linenumber2=$(( linenumber + 1 ))

#find string of that line
linecontent=$(sed -n "$linenumber2"p < $file)
echo $linecontent
#if it isn't match2 then add match2
if [ "$linecontent" != "$match_following_line" ]
then
    awk -v line="$linenumber" -v text="\n$insert" ' NR!=line{print} NR==line{print $0 text}' $file > $testfile
fi
```

The file `words` looks like this:

```
A
B
C
D
match1
After execusion the line before this line will become "line_insert1"
E
```

The output from this file `testfile` will be:

```
A
B
C
D
match1
line_insert1
After execusion the line before this line will become "line_insert1"
E
```

For several lines I have tried:

```
match[0]='match1'
match_follower[0]='following1'
insert[0]='line_insert1'

match[1]='match2'
match_follower[1]='following2'
insert[1]='line_insert2'

match[2]='match3'
match_follower[2]='following3'
insert[2]='line_insert3'

file='1.csv'

for i in 0 1 2
do

#find linenumber for the first match
linenumber=$(awk -v myvar="${match[$i]}" '$0~myvar {print NR}' $file)
echo $linenumber
#calculate linenumber for the comming line
linenumber2=$(( linenumber + 1 ))

#find string of that line
linecontent=$(sed -n "$linenumber2"p < $file)
#if it isn't match_follower then add insert
if [ "$linecontent" != "${match_follower[$i]}" ]
then
        awk -v line="$linenumber" -v text="${insert[$i]}" ' NR!=line{print} NR==line{print $0 text}' $file > $file
fi
done
```

When I try to do this for several strings I don't know what to do as the awk writes to $testfile and overwrites that file in every loop. Does anyone know a good solution to this?

Comment: Please give an example file and desired output.

Comment: realize that `awk` has all the tools you need to read thru the file one time (maybe 2), and perform all the operations and logic you need in one set of code. Each time you code finds a match for a rule, set a flag var for that condition (i.e. `/match1/{m1=1}`). Then test your flag condtions, and when it (or all) are true, perform your operation.(`if {m1 && m2 && ! m3) {do stuff}`) You can also rely on just `print $0` to output the current line as needed. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
match[0]='match1'
match_follower[0]='following1'
insert[0]='line_insert1'

match[1]='match2'
match_follower[1]='following2'
insert[1]='line_insert2'

match[2]='match3'
match_follower[2]='following3'
insert[2]='line_insert3'

file='1.csv'

for i in 0 1 2
do

sed -E -i '/'"${match[$i]}"'/!b;n;/^'"${match_follower[$i]}"'|^'"${insert[$i]}"'/! i '"${insert[$i]}" ${file}

done
```

In order to use shell variables in `sed` the `''` had to be closed and open `""` for the variable then reopen `''` etc etc. This is why so much qoute in the sed line.

At first for cycle sed look like this:

```
sed -E -i '/match1/!b;n;/^following1|^line_insert1/! i line_insert1' 1.csv
```

Where

`/match1/!` find line that NOT (`!`) contain `match1` then `b` prevent to execute rest of the sed script on the current line. If that not the case sed script continue with `n` (`;` are separators between command blocks)

`n` will read the next line into pattern space, so the rest of the sed script will be executed on the next line.

`/^following1|^line_insert1/!` This make sure the script only insert line if current pattern space(line) NOT (`!`) start (`^`) with `following1` or `line_insert1`  , `-E` switch required to this regexp to work.

`i line_insert1` this is the actual line that insert a new line with the given text `i` is the insert operator.

`sed -i` change file in place.

---

With AWK just replace sed line with this:

```
awk -v v_match="${match[$i]}" -v v_follower="${match_follower[$i]}" -v v_insert="${insert[$i]}" '
{if (find_match == 1  && $0 !~ v_insert  && $0 !~ v_follower  ) { find_match=0 ; print v_insert } { find_match=0 ;print } } 
$0 ~ v_match { find_match=1 }' ${file} > tmp_file && mv tmp_file ${file}
```

`$0 ~ v_match { find_match=1 }` if line is `${match[$i]}` set `find_match` variable to `1`

`{if (find_match == 1  && $0 !~ v_insert  && $0 !~ v_follower  ) {find_match=0 ; print v_insert } { find_match=0 ;print } }` if `find_match` is `1` and line is not `${match_follower[$i]}` or `${insert[$i]}` then print `${insert[$i]}` else just print current line, set `find_match` to `0` in both case.

`> tmp_file && mv tmp_file ${file}` as awk not have change file in place feature like sed have a temporally file is required (`tmp_file`).

Comment: Thanks, the sed one liner works perfectly. Do you mind explaning what's going on in it?
`sed -i '/'"${match[$i]}"'/!b;n;/^'"${match_follower[$i]}"'/! i'"${insert[$i]}" ${file}`

Comment: Of some reason the sed script only works once. When I run the script again the file shouldn't be changed. However the lines are added again.

Comment: `|^'"${insert[$i]}"'` and `-E` had to be added to deal situations where line already added, not get added again, i will update the description soon what sed is doing.

Comment: Fixed the awk as well, and added more verbose explanations how sed is doing this. Let me know if you have any more issue with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful and interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to locate the target line position in advance may not work well
for the case the line number dynamically changes especially when
multiple lines are added one by one.

Please try the following:

```
#/bin/bash

declare -a match=("match1" "match2" "match3")
declare -a match_follower=("following1" "following2" "following3")
declare -a insert=("line_insert1" "line_insert2" "line_insert3")

file="1.csv"

declare -a list
readarray -t list < "$file"

for i in "${!match[@]}"; do
    for j in "${!list[@]}"; do
        if [[ ${match[$i]} = ${list[$j]} ]] && [[ ${match_follower[$i]} != ${list[$(( $j + 1 ))]} ]]; then
            k=$(( j + 1 ))
            list=( "${list[@]:0:$k}" "${insert[$i]}" "${list[@]:$k}" )
            j=$k
        fi
    done
done

(IFS=$'\n'; echo "${list[*]}")
```

Sample input `1.csv`

```
A
B
C
D
match1
After execusion the line before this line will become "line_insert1"
E
F
G
match2
following2
After execusion the line before this line will NOT become "line_insert2"
H
I
J
match3
After execusion the line before this line will become "line_insert3"
K
```

Output

```
A
B
C
D
match1
line_insert1
After execusion the line before this line will become "line_insert1"
E
F
G
match2
following2
After execusion the line before this line will NOT become "line_insert2"
H
I
J
match3
line_insert3
After execusion the line before this line will become "line_insert3"
K
```

- `readarray` reads the input file into an array, setting the array element
  to each line. (bash 4.0 or newer is required.)
- The script iterates over the lines. If a line matches with
  `${match[$i]}` and the next line differs from `${match_follower[$i]}`
  then insert the element `${insert[$i]}` in the next index.